# Visual studio requires a newer version of windows to display this content

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2019

I've just installed visual studio 2019 and loaded "Get started" project but when I try to run it I get an error message "Visual Studio requires a newer version of Windows to display this content. Please update to Windows 10, version 1809(10.0.17763.0) or later.

I've gone into Windows settings and clicked "Check for Updates" and it says "You're up to date Last checked: Today 20:52"

Comment: What version of Windows are you running?

Comment: Windows 10 comes in many versions. Version 1809 is the second latest upgrade available, 1903 is the latest, but is not yet marked as fully available, meaning that Microsoft is gradually rolling that one out. You can find out what version of windows 10 you are using by going to Settings->System->Info, and scroll down.

Comment: Edition: Windows 10 Home. Version: 1803. Is it possible to get version 1809?

Comment: Yeah. Download it from Microsoft site.